# error happening in thrift

Tags: javascript, evernote

I'm getting this error when running my script. Not sure why this is happening. Seems like there may be a bug in Evernote's Thrift

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:733:13)
    at Object.BinaryParser.fromString (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/protocol/binaryProtocol.js:502:12)
    at BinaryProtocol.writeString (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/protocol/binaryProtocol.js:148:30)
    at BinaryProtocol.writeType (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/protocol/binaryProtocol.js:168:25)
    at new Thrift.List.write (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:275:20)
    at new Thrift.Struct.write (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:530:17)
    at Thrift.Struct.write (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:530:17)
    at Thrift.Method.sendRequest (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/thrift.js:162:15)
    at NoteStoreClient.updateNote (/Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/thrift/gen-js2/NoteStore.js:1700:8)
    at /Users/sam/Documents/evernote/node_modules/evernote/lib/stores.js:106:14`

Comment: Can you provide your code and/or what you have done?

Comment: my code can be found here: https://github.com/sfahlberg/evernote_automation/blob/master/app.js

Comment: and which line does this error come from?

Comment: it's coming from line 44 https://github.com/sfahlberg/evernote_automation/blob/master/tomorrow_becomes_today.js#L44

Answer (score 0):

[NoteStore#updateNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateNote) takes a `Note` object as an argument. You should be able to instantiate it by `new Evernote.Note()`. Note that it seems you don't have to set `title` if you are not going to update it.